# Background body scroll up when navbar collapses on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I click the nav item , navbar closes and background body also scroll up to the same size until navbar closes and stop scrolling when navbar closed. This only happen on mobile devices. I tried `overflow: hidden` but it is not working.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Azam Badar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor03" aria-controls="navbarColor03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#techstack">Techstack</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#socialwall">Socialwall</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#let'stalk">Let's Talk</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Please see below 2 images, when I click the nav icon and navbar opens , body (myprojects in this case) scoroll down and vice versa.

[image]
[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

CSS code would be great to see but i guess you missed `position:absolute` somewhere. Your navigation has to be positioned as absolute and given `z-index` greater than the container or you wont be able to see it. Hope this helped , if not , share the CSS code so I can check it out :)

Comment: I added two images, please have a look.

Comment: pictures are good but we need your CSS code , like u wrote HTML in your question. Do the same thing for css and Java Script :)